# Joomla template displaying in iframe

Tags: templates, iframe, joomla

I have a site that requires an iframe for inserting a reservation widget into a Joomla article. I have no problems displaying the iframe in the article, but the problem is the template is also displaying in the article. It's as if the iframe wraps the entire site inside the article also. I only need the reservation widget to appear. You can see it here http://www.archersinn.com/reservations. The reservations widget is a third party my client uses so I just need to figure out how to display it properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can show only the component using this parameter at the end of your joomla url

```
?tmpl=component
```

http://www.archersinn.com/reservations?tmpl=component

But you need to do this before this page.

In the page you insert your code for reservations you have style from Joomla, but is not joomla, I'm right?

Comment: The `iframe` is pointing to an external site, otherwise it would have been the perfect solution.

Comment: But why is Joomla style from Rt template? the solution maybe is delete that style?

Answer (score 1):

In your `iframe` you are calling an external webpage. If you got control over the look and feel of the external widget site, you may configure that page to look like your current page - http://www.archersinn.com/reservations, with the introduction and title etc.

Instead of linking the menu item `reservations` to an article within your site, you may consider pointing the menu item to the external site - https://secure.rezovation.com/Reservations/CheckAvailability.aspx?s=H4LUxh0dk0&type=raw. Change the menu item type to `External Link` and set to open it in the parent window.

Comment: Your solution would be perfect except I don't have control over the look and feel of the external page. The reservations page needs to show the rates as it does now so I need to embed that booking system. I suppose I could try contacting the company controlling that system and see if they can either format it the way I need or remove the styling.

Answer (score 1):

The iframe is pointing to https://secure.rezovation.com/Reservations/CheckAvailability.aspx?s=w36FN02v7M&type=raw but that site has made a custom template for you so that it matches the look and feel of your website.

So it's not supposed to be an iframe at all. Just change the URL of the Reservation button to the following and you should be sorted: https://secure.rezovation.com/Reservations/CheckAvailability.aspx?s=w36FN02v7M&type=raw

Many booking systems do it this way. They have the booking engine on their own system and redirect back to your website at the end of the transaction.

Comment: Your solution would work except that the page needs to have the rates as it does now. I see how the booking system creates it's own template so I might just need to contact them and see if they'll remove the styling.